# Prove that $\alpha=\beta=\gamma$ where $\alpha,\beta, \gamma$ are complex numbers.

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $x,y,z$ be non-zero real numbers. Suppose $\alpha,\beta, \gamma$ are complex numbers such that $|\alpha|=|\beta|=|\gamma|=1$. If $x+y+z=0=\alpha x+\beta y+\gamma z,$ then prove that $\alpha=\beta=\gamma$.

I was trying to use the property that $\alpha\overline{\alpha}=|\alpha|^2=1$, $\beta\overline{\beta}=|\beta|^2=1$ and $\gamma\overline{\gamma}=|\gamma|^2=1$ in the following way:

It is given that $$x+y+z=0=\alpha x+\beta y+\gamma z$$ $$\implies \overline{\alpha}(x+y+z)=0=x+\overline{\alpha}(\beta y+\gamma z)...(1)$$ $$\implies \overline{\beta}(x+y+z)=0=y+\overline{\beta}(\gamma z+\alpha x)...(2)$$ $$\implies\overline{\gamma}(x+y+z)=0=z+\overline{\gamma}(\alpha x+\beta y)...(3)$$

Adding $(1),(2)$ and $(3)$, we have $\overline{\alpha}(\beta y+\gamma z)+\overline{\beta}(\gamma z+\alpha x)+\overline{\gamma}(\alpha x+\beta y)=0.$

This implies that $x(\alpha\overline{\beta}+\alpha\overline{\gamma})+y(\beta\overline{\alpha}+\beta\overline{\gamma})+z(\gamma\overline{\alpha}+\alpha\overline{\beta})=0.$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Hint: the polynomial is homogenous.

Comment: @freshman I have edited the post and have written what I have tried.

Comment: Use $x+y+z=0$ iff $x=-y-z$ and put it on $\alpha x+\beta y+\gamma z=0$. You will get $(\beta-\alpha)y+(\gamma-\alpha)z=0$. Can you conclude now?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $\alpha=\beta=\gamma$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1549654/prove-that-alpha-beta-gamma)

Comment: @freshman following from your comment: We have $(\beta-\alpha)y+(\gamma-\alpha)z=0$. Now since $y,z$ are non-zero real numbers, implies that $\beta-\alpha=0$ and $\gamma-\alpha=0$. This implies that $\alpha=\beta=\gamma$. Do you mean this?

Comment: In fact you should try something by contradictions like "suppose $\beta-\alpha\neq0$ or $\gamma-\alpha\neq0$". Your conclusion doesn't seem correct to me. By the way, look my earlier comment. This question is duplicated